# php sql insert multiple

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to convert data from one table to another, from the ITEMS_VEHICLES table to the VEHICLES table. My code is this:

```
$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items_vehicles", $db); 
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
    if ($rs[motorbike] > 0) { mysql_query("INSERT INTO vehicles (type, player, hp) VALUES('1', '$rs[player]', '50')"); }
    if ($rs[banger] > 0) { mysql_query("INSERT INTO vehicles (type, player, hp) VALUES('2', '$rs[player]', '50')"); 
}
```

etc

But the $rs[motorbike] and other fields i want them to insert that code the amount of times in that column. Example, if $rs[motorbike] was '5', I want that insert query ran 5 times.

I'm in a bind, not sure how to do it.

Comment: This: `'$rs[player]'` should be `'{$rs[player]}'` or `'".$rs[player]."'`. You should also avoid using inherent strings (such as `$rs[player]`, see `player`) and instead use quoted strings like `'{$rs["player"]}'`.

Comment: Please put quotes around your array keys, and turn on `display_errors`, as your code produces all sorts of notices you must not be seeing.  `$rs['motorbike']`

Comment: Your code as is will produce lots of notices like `Notice:  Use of undefined constant motorbike`

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your explanation, something like this:

```
$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items_vehicles", $db); 
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $rs['motorbike']; $i++) { 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO vehicles (type, player, hp) VALUES('1', '$rs[player]', '50')"); 
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $rs['banger']; $i++) { 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO vehicles (type, player, hp) VALUES('2', '$rs[player]', '50')");    
    }
    etc
}
```

Comment: thanks, what if i wanted a restriction of 5 max on each one, is that hard to edit?

Comment: `for ($i = 1; $i <= min(5, $rs['motorbike']); $i++)`

Comment: Is it running more than once for the same user? e.g. once with `$rs['motorbike']` set to 4 and another with it set to 2, for example? That would make 6 in total, because each time it runs the number is less than 5. If not that, I don't know why it's not working. `min(5, $rs['motorbike'])` should return the minimum value of either 5 or `$rs['motorbike']`.

Comment: oh, i want it to either be $rs[motorbike] or 5 max. So if rs[motorbike] is over 5, then it just stops, 5 being max.

Comment: Yes, so you want the minimum of 5 and `$rs['motorbike']`; but if there is more than one record for a given user, he might still end up with more than 5 doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `if` statements with a `for` loop that runs `x` times, where `x` is the size of `$rs['motorbike']`.